# Expected value of Combined random variable with function E(X^2Y^3)

Tags: statistics

ok, so the question goes like this. see embedded link [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spXzb.jpg)

I have no problem finding E[X] and E[Y] using iterative expectation. Unfortunately, X and f(Y|X) is not independent therefore simply multiplying E[X] and E[Y] will not give the final outcome. Any suggestion on how to do this? or Must we use rigorous method of integration etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start you with a hint to give you chance to finish it yourself (and because I'm on my phone)

$$ E[Y^2X^3] = E[E[Y^2X^3 | X]] = E[X^3E[Y^2 | X]] $$

Comment: Thanks, thats more than enough :) i think i tried from bottoms up approach.